# Curl from command line to download zip file

Tags: curl, download, cygwin

I'm attempting to use Curl form within cygwin to download a zip file that contains dozens of photos.

Problem is I don't have the URL for the actual zip file, rather when clicking on the 'download' link it calls another URL that's dynamically generated and only exists for less than a second so I'm unable to call that URL directly.

The URL which is used when one clicks on 'download' looks like https://www.testsite/event=dload&task_id=11111

When I use 'copy as Curl' from within Chrom DevTools after clicking on that URL and run that exact script it downloads the source of the web page but not the files itself.

My question is - is there any way to use Curl to actually download this zip file? If not, is there another tool I should consider? Eventually this will be a full-blown app but right now I'm just experimenting in the shell.

Comment: You might be able to use a library to interact with the webpage and programmatically click the link. When the unique url is generated, you could then pass this to curl. I don't know any offhand.

Comment: I can do that but I'm trying to avoid having the page up on the screen which I believe would be required in order for the link to be programmatically clicked. On all other aspects of this site I'm able to use curl without the site ever being launched in a browser. Also, I don't believe it would be fast enough as the link would 'die' before curl can do its magic.

Comment: I meant a library capable of requesting a page to load without a GUI browser (they exist). You may have to forgo curl and have this browser download the file when the server returns it, since the site may be relying on the same connection to ensure the link was downloaded from the same source.